# How to iterate over childnodes in boost::propertytree, if these have childs itself?

Tags: xml, boost-propertytree

I load a boost::property_tree::ptree from an XML-file, that looks somewhat like this:

```
<bla>
   <foo>
       <element id="1" type="..." path="..."/>
       <element id="2" type="..." path="..."/>
       <element id="3" type="..." path="..."/>
       <otherelement/>
   </foo>
</bla>
```

I load that into a property-tree with read_xml. Now I want to build a vector containing structs, that resemble the `element`-tags. I can do the following:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type& node, tree.get_child("bla.foo"))
{
    if (node.first == "element")
    {
                 ...
    }
}
```

So far it's good, but I have problems to get the data in the element. `node.second` should contain that, but how do I access it properly? `node.second.get("xmlattr.type")` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

After using the Google-Fu in the right way, I found an answer myself in [this blogentry](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/parsing-xml-with-boost/). The correct way is `node.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.type")`. Except I got the xmlattr-thing wrong, the way to avoid the compiler-error I got is the use of the template-syntax.